# Passing around generic classes in Dataflow

Tags: java, generics, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm using the Apache Beam version of Dataflow, and am currently running into an issue when I try to create a PTransform that outputs a generic class. Here's a minimal example of such a transform, which simply outputs a type repeatedly.

```
public class BadTransform
    extends PTransform<PCollection<Result>, PCollection<Class<? extends Type1>>> {

  @Override
  public PCollection<Class<? extends Type1>> expand(
      PCollection<Result> input) {
    return input.apply(
        ParDo.of(
            new DoFn<Result, Class<? extends Type1>>() {
              @ProcessElement
              public void processElement(ProcessContext processContext) throws Exception {
                processContext.output(Type2.class);
              }
            }));
  }
}
```

This transform compiles without issue, but when run, it yields the error message `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.beam.sdk.repackaged.com.google.common.reflect.Types$WildcardTypeImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.TypeVariable`

I don't have any specialized coder for this.

Can Beam/Dataflow handle passing around generic classes like this? If it can, what am I currently doing wrong?

Comment: Please include the complete exception stack trace, not just the message.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessarily safe to cast `Class<Type2>` into a `Class<Type1>`. Even if `Type2` is a subclass of `Type1`, it depends on the [variance](
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) of `Class<T>` as to whether `Class<Type2>` is a subtype of `Class<Type1>`, `Class<Type1>` is a subtype of `Class<Type2>` or they may be unrelatable.

Could you instead ask a question about the problem you are trying to solve, and then we could maybe identify ways to accomplish that using Beam?